# Igbt switching for magnetic coils

Tags: switching, pspice, igbt

I am constructing igbt based switching circuit for switching multiple coils with a proper time delay for a scientific experiment. I need to simulate the circuit before doing on board. I am using pspice. It doesn't have igbt gate driver as I require. How to go about it?

Comment: Make ideal voltage clock source and add series gate resistance equivalent to gate drive impedance plus gate resistor...

Answer (score 1):

First you design the circuit on paper using equations. Then you verify the circuit with pspice. Why do you do it this way? because models are notorious for being wrong or only partially model the way a part behaves. Having a datasheet and some hand calculations will help you verify the spice circuit.

Find the part you want, then download the spice file.

- Change “Files of type:” Select your .LIB file and left click “Open.”
- Import .LIB File into Your Project Select your project tab. Left click “Add File.” “Library” folder. Select “Schematic Library” and copy it.

Source: [IMporting Spice Models into Orcad](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND6045-D.PDF)
Or use LTspice, its way way better and its free with no limits.